# Python: Fast indexing of strings in nested list without loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have an array dataset from which I need to build D whose each element is a list of strings (Third column of dataset). The dataset looks like:

```
600,900,3418309  
600,900,3418309  
600,900,3418314   
600,900,3418314  
600,900,3418319   
600,900,3418319  
610,800,3418324  
610,700,3418324  
600,900,3418329  
620,900,3418329  
600,900,3418329  
600,900,3418334  
610,900,3418334  
600,900,3418339  
600,900,3418339  
600,900,3418339  
660,700,3418339  
610,800,3418339  
660,700,3418339  
600,900,3418339  
600,900,3418339
```

I want to check for every new string, and if it is not a part of any of the array element then append new string to only that array element.
Since the data on new strings to be added is large, I do not want to use loop. Is there any method to do it fast. I have to use Python.

Right now I am using the code, which is very slow:

```
for i in range(len(dataset)):
 for j in range(int(int(dataset[i,0]-600)),int(int(dataset[i,1]-600)+1)):
    
    if(str(dataset[i,2]) not in D[j]):
        
        D[j].append(str(dataset[i,2]))
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! You are certainly welcome to leave your question here, but there are some *serious* python wizards on Stack Overflow and I'm sure that posting your question there can get you an answer in the matter of minutes.

Comment: Why do you do if then pass them else? You could negate the if and drop the pass/else

Comment: @kbrose I have updated the code in question based on your suggestion. But still it is very slow. Can it be further improvised?

Comment: i am not an expert, but pandas couldnt work in this case? They have highly optimized performance for some tasks.

Comment: Have you tried making it a set instead of a list? Sets are optimized for containment checking.

Comment: Can you please give an example of you input data within your post? It makes it easier to test a solution.

Comment: @n1k31t4 I have updated the question to include a sample of the dataset.

Comment: @shaifaliGupta - I am not quite sure I understand what you need to do. Could you show the expected result for a part of your example dataset?

Answer (score 1):

*This answers assumes I have correctly understood the question... I can alter my answer if OP updates the question with more details*

Using your example data, you can use Pandas easily drop all duplicates.

### Setup

First dump your data above into a Dataframe with three columns (one for each of the items in each row.

Import pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
```

import your data - assuming it is a list of lists - each of your rows is a list  of three items, so we have three columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(your_list_of_lists, columns=["col1", "col2", "col3"])
```

Have a look at the first 5 rows:

```
df.head()
   col1  col2     col3
0   600   900  3418309  
1   600   900  3418309  
2   600   900  3418314  
3   600   900  3418314  
4   600   900  3418319
```

The values will be integers by default, not strings (if they all were). But the solutions below should work the same in either case.

#### Solutions

If you want to get all unique values of `col3`, you can do one of the following:

```
uniques1 = set(df.col3)              # returns a Python set
uniques2 = df.col3.unique()          # returns a NumPy ndarray
uniques3 = df.col3.drop_duplicates() # returns a pandas Series object
```

If you want to remove only those rows where `col3` repeats itself consecutively (which in some cases could produce the same result as the methods above, depending on the data), then you can [look at the methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463985/pandas-drop-consecutive-duplicates) here. [**An example**] adapted for your columnar situation[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53609021/3126298):

```
def drop_consecutive_duplicates(a, col_name):      # returns the dataframe
    ...:         ar = a[col_name].values 
    ...:         return a[np.concatenate(([True],ar[:-1] != ar[1:]))]
```

### This will return the entire dataframe, which those rows of consecutive values removed.

### Performance

There are many other ways to achieve the same result. Of the above, the first method is the fastest (on your small dataset example). Here are the benchmarks:

```
In [23]: %timeit df.col3.drop_duplicates()                                      
263 µs ± 883 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [24]: %timeit df.col3.unique()                                               
37.2 µs ± 3.19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [25]: %timeit set(df.col3)                                                   
10.5 µs ± 45.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

The consective version:

```
In [26]: %timeit drop_consecutive_duplicates(df, "col3")                                                                                                                                                                                          
266 µs ± 3.61 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

I imagine the Pandas methods might be able to scale better to a DataFrame with many rows, so this example might be rather biased on the dummy dataset with only ~20 rows.

The final method clearly has a little bit of overhead as it has to perform some extra operations